# How do I make the download attribute work without redirecting?

Tags: html

I am trying to create a link to an mp3 file that fires off a download. However the download attribute is ignored and the browser just redirects instead. It works with text files but not mp3 files? Please advise, thanks.

```
<a href="100miles.mp3" download="100miles.mp3">Download Text</a>
```

Comment: What browser are you using that have this behavior?

Comment: Firefox and chrome

Comment: Thought data URI can help, but probably not good solution...